# Implementing different types of joins without database in java

Tags: java, database, join

I have 2 CSV files which contain 50 records of each. Now I have to read values from these CSV files and perform different join operation (full outer join, left outer join, etc). How do I do this?

Comment: You could see how far you can get using the `addAll()`, `containsAll()`, `retainAll()` and `removeAll()` methods offered by the `Set` interface.

Comment: What do you join on? A common column? Multiple columns? Something else?

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please tag it as such.

Answer (score 2):

Load those two files in memory, and use loops:

```
private List<TwoRecords> innerJoin(List<Record1> list1, List<Record2> list2) {
    List<TwoRecords> result = new ArrayList<TwoRecords>();
    for (Record1 r1 : list1) {
        for (Record2 r2 : list2) {
            if (r1.getSomeField() != null 
                && r1.getSomeField().equals(r2.getSomeField())) {
                result.add(new TwoRecords(r1, r2));
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: could u give a descrption of the  above code i dont know anything about list's and i want the code in java . IS the above code in java . ?

Comment: Yes, it's Java code. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/ and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/index.html. The collections framework is a must-know of any Java programmer.