# how to perform joins in java without database

Tags: java, collections

I need to perform Joins on 2 tables (that I have read from 2 CSV files) without use of database. I have no idea on collections (List, ArrayList). If anyone can give a detail piece of sample code on any one type of join that would be helpful.

For example I have 2 lists :

```
a=[2,3,4]
b=[3,4,5]
```

If it is an inner join
output: `[3,4]`

Tried so far:

```
for i in a:
  for j in i:
     if (i==j):
          print(i)
```

Comment: Where have you saved those tables? In 2D array?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139886/implementing-different-types-of-joins-with-out-database-in-java

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have the following CSV files:

```
id,name,description
1,Foo,FooBar
2,Bar,BarFo
3,Hey,Ho
```

and the second one:

```
id,year
2,1990
1,1923
```

Then you could have the following structures (I'm skipping the constructors and methods for now):

```
public class Item {
  public String name;
  public String description;
}
```

and the second:

```
public class Date {
  public final int year;
}
```

Then you could have a third one:

```
public class Joined {
  public final Item item;
  public final Date date;
}
```

And then you could have a `Map<Integer,Joined>`, and you can read the first CSV and create the `Joined` objects with only the `Item` part filled out, then read the second CSV and you could fill up the `Date` part of the `Joined` object.

In this joining part, you can decide which joining type you want to implement.

If you have a different key, then you have to change the key of the `Map`, or you may need to create a new class if you have a complex key.